# Angular6 universal giving continues Error on console

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6, angular-universal

I am using angular 6 and implemented the angular universal for server side page rendering, 
Everything works fine but I am getting continues error in my console.

```
ERROR [Error]
ERROR [Error]
```

And I have declared window as global variable still I am getting errors like this

> Unhandled Promise rejection: window.some_function is not a
>   function

my server.ts file
//

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// node run port
const port = 6065;

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = port || process.env.PORT;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();

const template = fs
    .readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'))
    .toString();
// Make all Domino types available as types in the global env.
Object.assign(global, domino.impl);
(global as any)['KeyboardEvent'] = domino.impl.Event;
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
win.Object = Object;
win.Math = Math;

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['navigator'] = mock.getNavigator();
global['branch'] = null;
global['object'] = win.object;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Text'] = win.Text;

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Your Angular Universal App is supposed to render on the server. You won't have access to the Window Object in there. You might want to move anything that you've attached to the Window Object somewhere else.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: isPlatformBrowser() {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: using the above condition we can handle the DOM objects, You have any idea about how to handle DOM objects that were used in core files of any third party module?

Comment: Try using domino maybe: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830#issuecomment-345228799

Comment: @David I am using the domino.

Comment: Sorry I did not read properly. What function is undefined exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your response, window is used in inner module files of module pdfjs-dist.

Comment: but this ERROR [Error] is coming continues, Have you any idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and started debugging server.js in my Visual Studio Code and what I had found: an error messages was caused by http requests from `TranslateHttpLoader` (I'm using ngx-translate), which was trying to load .json-files with translations. After some googling I found this [thread](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/754) where you can find how to enable server-side translation loading. After that error messages disappeared.

Comment: How do you debug server.js? Is there a plugin, or command? All I see is `Error [Error]`, which is not amazingly helpful.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin Hi did you figure out what was the error? I am also getting the same error as ERROR [Error].